# Unable to install ROS2 Foxy on RPI 4 running Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: ros2

I am unable to run the command  `sudo apt install ros-foxy-desktop`. Following the guide here: https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html. I am able to complete all the steps until the final install which gives these errors.

Any help would be much appreciated. I've already tried to install by the guide here https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html. Is it because I am running ubuntu 21.10 desktop and need to be running 20.04 server? The issue I run into with the 20.04 server is that I won't be able to connect to the university I am at wifi, the wifi uses PEAP and I don't know how to set that up with the server to connect to the wifi.

````
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-foxy-action-msgs : Depends: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) but it is not installable
                        Depends: ros-foxy-unique-identifier-msgs but it is not going to be installed
 ros-foxy-action-tutorials-interfaces : Depends: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) but it is not installable
 ros-foxy-actionlib-msgs : Depends: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) but it is not installable
 ros-foxy-builtin-interfaces : Depends: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) but it is not installable
 ros-foxy-composition-interfaces : Depends: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) but it is not installable
 ros-foxy-demo-nodes-cpp-native : Depends: ros-foxy-fastrtps but it is not installable
                                  Depends: ros-foxy-rmw-fastrtps-cpp but it is not installable
 ros-foxy-depthimage-to-laserscan : Depends: libopencv-core4.2 (>= 4.2.0+dfsg) but it is not installable
                                    Depends: ros-foxy-image-geometry but it is not going to be installed
 ros-foxy-diagnostic-msgs : Depends: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) but it is not installable
...
 ros-foxy-std-srvs : Depends: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) but it is not installable
 ros-foxy-stereo-msgs : Depends: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) but it is not installable
 ros-foxy-tf2-msgs : Depends: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) but it is not installable
 ros-foxy-tf2-py : Depends: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) but it is not installable
 ros-foxy-trajectory-msgs : Depends: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) but it is not installable
 ros-foxy-turtlesim : Depends: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) but it is not installable
 ros-foxy-visualization-msgs : Depends: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Foxy is build for 20.04 and as such there is not a 21.04 release you can install. You will either have to install 20.04 or run some sort of container(i.e. docker).

As for the PEAP authentication, I would potentially look at [this askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279762/how-to-connect-to-wpa2-peap-mschapv2-enterprise-wifi-networks-that-dont-use-a-c) thread.